# How can I implement the use of two textboxes for my calculator?

Tags: vb.net

The purpose of my assignment is to create a calculator that uses number inputs from two textboxes. The calculator works when only dealing with a single textbox(boxequation1) but I need it to accept another input from the other textbox(boxequation2). Is there any way to input a number into boxequation1, select an operation, input a number into boxquation2, and then compute the result?

```
    Public Class Form1
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles num0.Click, num1.Click, num2.Click, num3.Click, num4.Click, num5.Click, num6.Click, num7.Click, num8.Click, num9.Click, opdivision.Click, opmultiply.Click, opdecimal.Click, opclear.Click, opminus.Click, opadd.Click, opequal.Click
    Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    If button.Name = "num1" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "1"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num2" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "2"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num3" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "3"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num4" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "4"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num5" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "5"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num6" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "6"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num7" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "7"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num8" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "8"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num9" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "9"
    End If
    If button.Name = "num0" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "0"
    End If
    If button.Name = "opdecimal" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "."
    End If
    If button.Name = "opequal" Then
        Dim equation1 As String = boxequation1.Text
        Dim equation2 As String = boxequation2.Text
        Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(equation1, Nothing)

        boxresult.Text = result
    End If
    If button.Name = "opminus" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "-"
        boxoperator.Text = boxoperator.Text + "-"
    End If
    If button.Name = "opmultiply" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "*"
        boxoperator.Text = boxoperator.Text + "x"
    End If
    If button.Name = "opdivision" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "/"
        boxoperator.Text = boxoperator.Text + "÷"
    End If
    If button.Name = "opadd" Then
        boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text + "+"
        boxoperator.Text = boxoperator.Text + "+"
    End If
    If button.Name = "opclear" Then
        boxequation1.Clear()
        boxoperator.Clear()
        boxresult.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub opbackspace_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles opbackspace.Click
    boxequation1.Text = boxequation1.Text.Remove(boxequation1.Text.Count - 1)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can I advise you a cleaner way? For example, you can put the number or symbol in buttons Tag property, then your clickbutton sub can be one line, like this  boxequation1.Text & = button .Tag instead of and if function for each button.

Comment: @CruleD great suggestion! You can carry it one step further and use the Text property of the button which is probably just the number displayed in the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a lot of fun with your homework.

Now... I'm not sure how I should do to help you. I initially wanted to code it and obfuscate parts of the code so you could check at what's clear and understand the rest by yourself, but on the other hand I have no idea if that would really help. I though that maybe you would do better with more explanations.

So I re-coded the whole thing, loosely based on what you posted earlier.
I heavily commented my work so you will be able to understand why I did things that war, but really you can and should ask me questions about everything which isn't cristal clear in this.
And, once you feel more confident about it, you should scrap my work and code it again, but from scratch this time. You're doing this to learn, after all!

Here what it looks like:

.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.[image]

Here's a very cusomized New() Sub. It's not how I coded it; I needed only the 3 first lines of this monstruosity, but I wanted you to see the rest of it because that's how I set up my controls in the designer.
You should set up your controls names, texts and tags in the designer, really. *This part really is here only because it was easier to show you these settings this way*.

```
Private Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    _currentTextBox = Number1TextBox
    _locked = False
    ResultsTextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    ResultsTextBox.Text = "SUPER DUPER CALCULATOR"
    For Each textBox As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox In {ResultsTextBox, Number1TextBox, Number2TextBox}
        'This prevent the user from writing in your textboxes instead of using the buttons.
        textBox.ReadOnly = True
    Next

    'I used the .Text and .Tag properties to make the code easier to manage. Observe:
    num0Button.Text = "0"
    num1Button.Text = "1"
    num2Button.Text = "2"
    num3Button.Text = "3"
    '...
    num9Button.Text = "9"
    opAddButton.Text = "+"
    opMinusButton.Text = "-"
    opMultiplyButton.Text = "x"
    opDivideButton.Text = "÷"
    For Each button As Button In {num1Button, num2Button, num3Button, num4Button, num5Button, num6Button, num7Button, num8Button, num9Button}
        button.Tag = "number"
    Next
    For Each button As Button In {opAddButton, opMinusButton, opMultiplyButton, opDivideButton}
        button.Tag = "operation"
    Next
    num0Button.Tag = "numberZero"
    opDecimalButton.Tag = "decimal"
    opBackspaceButton.Tag = "backspace"
    opEqualButton.Tag = "equal"
End Sub
```

**And now for the real code: the subs that your class will need and use:**

```
'Class variables are useful to remember informations which will be useful at several unrelated places.
'_currentTextBox is a pointer to the TextBox which is currently being filled
Private _currentTextBox As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox = Number1TextBox
'_Llocked will prevent the user from messing with the calculator after he pressed "equal"
Private _locked As Boolean = False

'I didn't like this idea but I went with it since it was your initial method.
'Notice how shoter this iteration of your idea is. Strive to shorten your code while making your variable names much easier to read.
'For real, make sure your variables are aptly names. Every control should be identified as such (the button num0 should be names num0Button for example)
'Code is hard enough to read without making it sibylline
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles num0Button.Click, num1Button.Click, num2Button.Click, num3Button.Click, num4Button.Click, num5Button.Click, num6Button.Click, num7Button.Click, num8Button.Click, num9Button.Click, opDivideButton.Click, opMultiplyButton.Click, opDecimalButton.Click, opClearButton.Click, opMinusButton.Click, opAddButton.Click, opEqualButton.Click, opBackspaceButton.Click
    'DirectCast is more strick than CType. For this operation, it doesn't really make a difference, but that's the one you want anyway.
    Dim button As System.Windows.Forms.Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)

    'The boolean _locked prevent the user from messing with your beautiful calculator.
    If Not _locked Then
        'This is where the .Tag property save lifes. All numbers (but zero) are "number" now. BAM!
        Select Case button.Tag.ToString
            Case "number"
                _currentTextBox.Text += button.Text
            Case "numberZero"
                'You don't want your clever teacher to try to divide by zero, or create a number with 5 zeros before the actual number.
                'This is how you can do this.
                If _currentTextBox.Text.Length > 0 Then
                    _currentTextBox.Text += button.Text
                End If
            Case "decimal"
                If _currentTextBox.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso Not _currentTextBox.Text.Contains(".") Then
                    _currentTextBox.Text += button.Text
                End If
            Case "operation"
                ResetOperationTextBoxes()
                'here's a nifty visual cue about which operation has been selected. It's not really important.
                button.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
                'This label will be used to Calculate() the operation. It's important!
                OpLabel.Text = button.Text
            Case "backspace"
                If _currentTextBox.Text.Length > 0 Then
                    _currentTextBox.Text = _currentTextBox.Text.Substring(0, _currentTextBox.Text.Length - 1)
                End If
            Case "equal"
                'I could have put the code here instead of making another sub, but I didn't.
                'There are two valid reasons for this.
                '1- This code might be useful on it's own later: maybe something else will Calculate() or LockCalculator or ResetCalculator later.
                '2- try to avoid blobs of code. A big and complex sub is easier to understand when it's divided between several clean and clear smaller subs.
                '   (of course, you cannot always subdivise Subs. Use common sense)
                Calculate()
        End Select
    End If

    'This check is all alone because I want it to work even if the calculator is locked.
    If button.Tag.ToString = "clear" Then
        ResetCalculator()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Calculate()
    'Always make checks to make sure that things are going the way you think they should be going.
    'for example, here I want to have 2 numbers and an operation, er else I'll just ignore this click.
    If Number1TextBox.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso Number2TextBox.Text.Length > 0 And OpLabel.Text <> "?" Then
        'If the user could mess with the textboxes, i would have to make further checks to avoid crashes, but I already force the user to use only numbers se we're cool.
        Dim number1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Number1TextBox.Text)
        Dim number2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Number2TextBox.Text)
        Dim result As Double

        Select Case OpLabel.Text
            Case "+"
                result = number1 + number2
            Case "-"
                result = number1 - number2
            Case "x"
                result = number1 * number2
            Case "÷"
                result = number1 / number2
        End Select

        ResultsTextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
        ResultsTextBox.Text = result.ToString
        LockCalculator(True)
    End If
End Sub

'By using a boolean to signify to this Sub if I want to lock or unlock things, I make it easier to automatize this operation (and I have only one Sub instead of two).
Private Sub LockCalculator(ByVal isLocked As Boolean)
    _locked = isLocked
    'I'm kinda cheating here: I put the calculator inside a GroupBox just so I could be lazier and do this.
    'Being lazy is great for a coder, as long as you think ahead (and avoid being a nuisance to yourself when you'll come back to this code and weep).
    For Each control As System.Windows.Forms.Control In CalculatorGroupBox.Controls
        control.Enabled = Not isLocked
    Next
    'Except that I want this button to always be available, so I enable it. This operation wouldn't be necessary if isLocked is True, but checking for that is longer than just doing it.
    opClearButton.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub ResetCalculator()
    ResetNumberTextBoxes()
    ResetOperationTextBoxes()
    LockCalculator(False)
    _currentTextBox = Number1TextBox
End Sub

Private Sub ResetNumberTextBoxes()
    For Each textBox As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox In {Number1TextBox, Number2TextBox}
        textBox.Text = ""
    Next
    'Mea Culpa: I shouldn't had done a For Each for 2 elements like that. I did it anyway. Please don't call the Fun Police on me.
    'Also, you can now guess that using For Each loops to set up controls is a work method I like. Some don't like that.
    'There is about as many ways to code something as there are coders. You have to find your own, sure, but then you'll get hired somewhere
    'and they will absolutely hate everything that you do that isn't done the way they like it. And they will be right. On a big project where
    'several coders works, at the same time and for month and years, you have to find a common ground or else the code will become a nightmare
    'to understand and maintain. Trust me: being able to adapt quickly to other's work methodology is a GREAT skill in this field of work.

    ResultsTextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    ResultsTextBox.Text = "SUPER DUPER CALCULATOR"
End Sub

Private Sub ResetOperationTextBoxes()
    For Each button As System.Windows.Forms.Button In {opAddButton, opMinusButton, opMultiplyButton, opDivideButton}
        button.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
    Next
    OpLabel.Text = "?"
End Sub

'This sub is great. It uses the _currentTextBox as a pointer. Maybe you're not familiar with pointers, I don't know. The short explanation is this:
'A pointer is like a phone number. You can give your number to several people without "losing" it. And if they call you and tell you something, they
'are all speaking to the same person.
'_currentTextBox is a pointer which can point toward Number1TextBox or Number2TextBox.
'This Event makes it so when the user click on Number1TextBox or Number2TextBox, the pointer updates it's "phone number" to the right box,
'so later when we'll write we'll write in the last one which was clicked on.
Private Sub NumberTextBoxes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Number1TextBox.Click, Number2TextBox.Click
    _currentTextBox = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
End Sub
```

Here you go. I hope that you'll have as much fun with coding as I did!

Before I go to sleep now, here's a few things that I think that you should make an effort to improve on:

**1**  Name your controls with really, really obvious names. Nobody care that the names are long, we all use the intelliSense anyway. But anything that we cannot guess at a glance is not clear enough!

**2**  Same thing with your variables. Same for everything which has a name, in fact. If you show your work to a teammate and he's not able to guess which control you're speaking about just by it's name, it's not clear enough!

**3**  The rest you will learn as you persevere through understanding your friend, the computer.

**4**  You should turn on Explicit and Strict mode. It'll help you understand the type you're working with and how they interact. It'll reduce dramatically the risk of awful manipulations. In fact, as though the more experience a coder has, the less he'll need these options, the more experienced a coder is, the more likely he'll be to have those two little lines of code at the beginning of all his works...

Here's how I begin every page of VB code at home:

.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.[image: Creation date, Author, etc.]

**4**  Ask questions! To me, to classmates, to teachers! Ask questions to everything that moves!

Good luck!

Comment: I just realized that, with this code, you cannot write a number which is smaller than 1 (because i forbid to start with zero). I'll let you engineer a fix for that. If you don't find how to do it, let me know and I'll help!